# Приём логов syslog на qt

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь слушать UDP сокет порт 514 для того чтобы отловить приходящие от сервера логи. Проблема в том что командой

```
 echo “hello” > /dev/udp/192.168.5.52/514
```

я получаю данные, а вот когда отправляют реальные логи, ничего нет.
В настройках syslog.conf указал

```
*.* @127.0.0.1:514
```

Сама программа приёма логов взята из документации qt:

```
void Server::initSocket()
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 514);

    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
}

void Server::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);

        processTheDatagram(datagram);
    }
}
```

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно, то ли проблемы с настройкой `syslog`, то ли с кодом, который привели, один к одному скопировав из доки.

Comment: Начните с запуска wireshark, Чтобы воочию наблюдать, как пакеты идут.